# Strange behavior with ViewModel and Closure in ZF2

Tags: php, callback, zend-framework2

I try to pass callback function to template which should will be called in template but callback is called directly after parameters has passed to method setVariable()

```
public function testAction() {
   $model = new ViewModel();
   $callback = function() {
      return new \stdClass();
   };
   $model->setVariable('call', $callback);

   \Zend\Debug\Debug::dump([
       get_class($callback), 
       get_class($model->getVariable('call'))
   ]);
}
```

Result bit strange:

```
array(2) {
 [0] => string(7) "Closure"
 [1] => string(8) "stdClass"
}
```

I do not understand why it happens. Is this bug or feature?

Comment: Not looked at look at [the code](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-view/blob/master/src/Variables.php#L146)? This shows the the call to `getVariable` in your debug is causing the closure to be invoked, if you want the *closure* then you may want to consider a view helper.

Comment: I see... Thank indicated on my mistake. I must would be check $this->variables type before ask the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view variables are stored as custom `ArrayObject` class `Zend\View\Variables`.

Call to `$viewModel->getVariable()` in your debug will proxy to the `offsetGet` method and [will cause the closure to be invoked](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-view/blob/master/src/Variables.php#L146).

The relevant code.

```
public function offsetGet($key)
{
    // ...
    $return = parent::offsetGet($key);
    // If we have a closure/functor, invoke it, and return its return value
    if (is_object($return) && is_callable($return)) {
        $return = call_user_func($return);
    }
    return $return;
}
```

If you want the closure object then you may want to consider using a view helper.